# Dismissed dialog is shown when returning to Actitiy,

Tags: android, dialog

I have actity wich raises an alert dialog.
Next, I dismiss the dialog and start a new Activity using an Intent. The dialog is dismissed, dialog's onStop and onDismissDialog Callbacks are notified, and the new activity is open.

Problem happens when I finish the second activity (either by calling Activity.finigh() or kill the proccess with adb). The first activity is shown again BUT the dialog is still there.

This does not happens if user exits the second activity by pressing back.

Sample code is:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Dialog title").setPositiveButton(
            "Open new activity", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                            SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

    builder.create().show();

}
}
```

I've tried to open and dismiss the dialog with Activity.showDialog() and Activity.dismissDialog(), but it works the same way,

What am I doing wrong?? Any ideas??

Thank you

Comment: Is the dialog actually being resurrected, or have you checked to see if it's just that your `onCreate()` is being run again?

Comment: dmon, you are right. onCreate() it's been called again, and that's why the dialog is shown again. Thano you.

Answer (score 0):

Let try `dismiss();` instead `dialog.dismiss();`

Answer (score 0):

Your last statement in the onCreate() method has a chained invocation with the last call being "show()" ... I'd recommend you remove that because everytime you create the Activity you're creating and showing the dialog.

Move the dialog creation statements to the onCreateDialog() method instead.  The, call "showDialog()" when you want it displayed.